# Click the next element

Tags: javascript

There's a div with the id "element" and within it is an anchor tag.  I need to find the element, then get the anchor tag on the inside and click it purely through javascript. (no jquery).

How might I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var e = document.getElementById('element');
var a = e.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
a.click();
```

Or as a one-line:

```
document.getElementById('element').getElementsByTagName('a')[0].click();
```